# Error de Terminating app due to uncaught exception al compilar app iOS hecha en Flutter

Tags: flutter, ios, swift

estoy intentando compilar una app hecha en flutter en iOS pero tengo el siguiente error.

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FLTWakelockApi api doesn't respond to @selector(toggleMsg:error:)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 757.5 - Device: iPhone 8 (3B4D1843-0845-4B98-8A76-5BE4DA2A7405) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPhone 8

Imagen igual a esta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que actualizar FLTWakelockApi.

La solución perfecta es actualizar flutter. En [este link al soporte de Flutter en GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89838), puedes ver la platica de la gente que está arreglando el programa. También puedes usar una librería: wakelock: 0.5.3+3 como se describe en el enlace.

Comment: Hola, como actualizo FLTWakelockApi no encuentro ninguna referencia en internet.

Comment: Con flutter creo. Es algo nuevo así q no hay mucha information solo fue descubriero have unos días parece.

Comment: pero yo no estoy usando la librería Pigeon

Comment: El link original tiene una solución manual como a 2/3 de la página

Comment: Sip la solución es usar una librería: wakelock: 0.5.3+3

Comment: Sería bueno agregar más detalles de la solución. Si el link deja de funcionar ya no será útil para otras personas que tengan el mismo problema.

Comment: La solución perfecta es actualizar flutter. Lo q tiene el link es temporal, es la platica de la gente q esta arreglando el programa.